# openMp basic and different outputs

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I just started learning openMP and and, as most newbies to parallel programming, I was writing a simple script to parallelize solving an integral. The following is the code that I wrote:

```
        num_chunks = 1000;
        int threads_assigned = 0;
        int num_threads = 10;// omp_get_num_threads();
        sum_arr = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * num_threads);
        memset(sum_arr, 0, num_threads);
        int sums_each_thread = num_chunks / num_threads;
        printf("num of threads = %d\n", num_threads);
        sum = 0.0;
        omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);
        chunk_size = 1.0/(double) num_chunks;
        double start_time = omp_get_wtime();
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
                int idx = omp_get_thread_num();
                if (idx == 0) threads_assigned = omp_get_num_threads();
                int sums_count;
                int loop_size = idx * sums_each_thread;
                for (sums_count = loop_size; sums_count < loop_size + sums_each_thread; sums_count++) {
                        printf("starting thread no %d\n", idx);
                        // double x = (idx * chunk_size) + (chunk_size / 2.0); simplified version in the next line
                        double x = chunk_size * (sums_count + 0.5);
                        double y = 4.0 / (1 + x*x);
                        sum_arr[idx - 1] += (y * chunk_size);
                        sum += y;
                }
                printf("ending thread no %d\n", idx);
        }
        double end_time = omp_get_wtime();
        printf("sum = %f, in time %f(s)\n", sum * chunk_size, end_time - start_time);
        int new_idx = 0;
        sum = 0.0;
        for(new_idx = 0; new_idx < num_threads; new_idx++) {
                sum += sum_arr[new_idx];
        }
        printf("arr sum = %f, with total assigned threads = %d\n", sum, threads_assigned);
```

I calculated the area by:

1 ) computing the sum of each area of rectangle.

2 ) computing the sum of all the heights (scalar sum) and then multiple by the chunk_size.

Mathematically both of the approaches yields same result but in this case of the above code, approach num 2 always shows the correct result and the approach num 1 fails.

Can anyone explain the cause?

Comment: Bug: `memset(sum_arr, 0, num_threads);`. Should be `sizeof(double)*num_threads`. Now why didn't you use calloc instead?

Comment: it's going to be very slow due to "false sharing" on `sum_arr`. Threads access the same line of cache causing expensive synchronization

Comment: Alright. @Lundin, the fix you suggested does not help with my question. And I'm new to C to just used what I found out the quickest

Comment: @tstanisl those things are for later I suppose. Please focus on my question. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadHasan It's a bug but not the answer to your OpenMP question. Hence it was posted as a comment and not an answer. The bug still needs to be fixed though.

Comment: maybe problem is that `sum += y;` operation is **not** atomic. Try to add `#pragma omp critical`

Comment: Thank you. yes I understand. But anyways the array indexing fixed the actual error which was in case of the result being different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

One is accessing invalid entry in `arr_sum` where element `-1` is accessed by the master thread.
Replace

```
sum_arr[idx - 1] += (y * chunk_size);
```

with

```
sum_arr[idx] += (y * chunk_size);
```

Another problem is modification of `sum` without synchronization.
Fetch previous `sum` and storing the updated value could be interleaved with similar operation by other thread. This *will* corrupt the result. This effect should be observable after removing `printf("starting thread no %d\n", idx);` from the inner loop. To fix it just use atomic updates.

```
#pragma omp atomic
sum += y;
```

Now sums computed in both ways are fine.

However, the program does scale poorly. One reason is "false sharing" on `arr_sum` when threads access the same line of cache causing costly synchronization at CPU level.

Another problem is using atomic instruction in critical `sum += y` which suffers from the very same problems.

---

Probably what you need is using reduction feature of OpenMP:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (int i = 0; i < num_chunks; ++i) {
        double x = chunk_size * (i + 0.5);
        double y = 4.0 / (1 + x*x);
        sum += y;
    }
```

Now it scales perfectly and is many (~100) times faster than the corrected loop from OP's question. It's so fast that `num_chunks > 10e7` is required to make the loop a significant part of execution time of the program.

Comment: Yes. @tstanisl thank you. The main problem was the array index. This code was written after a couple of minutes into the tutorial and by then the requirement was to only run without any syncing.

Comment: @MuhammadHasan, I'm glad that I could help. The "atomic" part is important as well. Otherwise, the result may be corrupted. Just remove the "printf" from the inner loop and run the program without `#pragma omp atomic`

Comment: yes agreed. but i avoided that with the use of array. I just created the sum var to test the 2 methods and I felt lazy to create another array.